# Classifying 3 groups statistically on a continuous scale

Tags: classification

I have 3 subsets, say- a,b,c which are derived from a single population of subjects. All subsets have an unequal "n", and are accompanied by a variable say 'L'.

My aim is to define a metric (based on values of variable L) that statistically differentiates between a, b and c.

E.g.- As L is a continuous variable (with values ranging from 1-10), I would expect to define a metric which goes like-

```
            1<a<4.2, 4.2<b<7 and 7<c<10
```

I have already performed a KW test followed by post-hoc Dunn's test and found that a,b and c are significantly different.

How should I go about defining the above mentioned metric?

Comment: Isn't L itself in that case a metric that differentiates your three groups?

Comment: @ArunJose yes, but I want to create these classes tha I mentioned above.

Comment: "E.g.- As L is a continuous variable (with values ranging from 1-10), I would expect to define a metric which says- 1" -- What does this mean?

Comment: Sorry just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Based on the edit, one possibility is to run a decision tree with L being independent variable. If a relationship exists, the function will return to you the ranges of L that maps to a specific category.